# Heroku rails Procfile

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

I am very new to Heroku.

I uploaded my Rails app to Heroku and would like to run it with Thin instead of Webrick. Following [Heroku’s guide](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/rails3) I am supposed to use `web: bundle exec rails server thin -p $PORT -e $RACK_ENV` to create the procfile. However I always get the response `web:: command not found`.

What am I missing?

Comment: did you add thin gem to your Gemfile? Actually I think you even need to create Procfile, if you are just doing it to run on thin server. To run with thin you just need to have it on gemfile. You just really need a Profile if your app has more processes

Comment: I have. Its weird though whouldn't I be able to create a procfile using the syntax above. It jsut keeps saying web: command not found

Comment: Have you tried install locally foreman (`gem install foreman`) and try to run your application to mimic what is happening on Heroku?

Answer (score 78, accepted):

You’re not supposed to run `web: bundle exec rails server thin -p $PORT -e $RACK_ENV` as a command, rather you create a new file called `Procfile` with that as its contents.

Either create the file and paste it in using your editor, or just do:

```
echo "web: bundle exec rails server thin -p \$PORT -e \$RACK_ENV" > Procfile
```

Comment: You sir deserve a clap. 
No where states that you shouldn't run "web: bundle exec rails server thin -p $PORT -e $RACK_ENV" as a command.
Thanks

Comment: @RedRory maybe so... but in that guide, the word 'Procfile' is linked to this [page](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/procfile) which shows how to setup a proper Procfile for heroku.

Comment: It's still pretty unclear from the documentation where you're supposed to create the Procfile. In the root directory? It's not immediately clear from the documentation. I'm guessing it's buried in there somewhere, but why not make it a bit more obvious by just saying, "run the following command in your shell: ..."

Comment: Indeed, it is buried in there: *Process types are declared via a file named Procfile placed in the root of your app*. I agree that it would be clearer if this info were marked up as a line of code or something that could be spotted by glancing through the article.

Comment: Thanks to whoever left a comment on the article regarding this.  I've made it a little clearer, emphasising "A Procfile is a text file named Procfile placed in the root of your application, that lists the process types in an application. " higher up in the article.

Comment: Is the Profile file supposed to be in the app directory? or the directory above that?

Comment: @Glide The `Procfile` goes in the top level of your project – not in the `app` dir, alongside it, next to `Gemfile`, `Rakefile` etc.

Answer (score 4):

Have you bundled thin into your application?

```
gem 'thin'
```

If not, you're looking at Rails trying to use the default server.  Personally, I would look at using Unicorn on Heroku, but be careful with how many workers you might need.

http://neilmiddleton.com/the-procfile-is-your-friend. Cached version: https://web.archive.org/web/20130926005616/http://www.neilmiddleton.com/the-procfile-is-your-friend

http://neilmiddleton.com/getting-more-from-your-heroku-dynos