# I am trying to push my app to heroku but doesn't go through

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku-postgres

Newbie here. I am trying to push my app to heroku, downloaded postgres and deleted gem 'sqlite3' from my gemfile. I need to update my database.yml and don't know what to put in front of "my_database_development" ?? that is my question. How do i set it up

This is my code

```
default: &default
  adapter: postgresql
  pool: <%= ENV.fetch("RAILS_MAX_THREADS") { 5 } %>
  timeout: 5000

development:
  <<: *default
  database: db/development.sqlite3

# Warning: The database defined as "test" will be erased and
# re-generated from your development database when you run "rake".
# Do not set this db to the same as development or production.
test:
  <<: *default
  database: db/test.sqlite3

production:
  <<: *default

  database: db/production.sqlite3
```

and I am trying to achieve following

```
development:
  adapter: postgresql
  database: my_database_development
  pool: 5
  timeout: 5000
test:
  adapter: postgresql
  database: my_database_test
  pool: 5
  timeout: 5000

production:
  adapter: postgresql
  database: my_database_production
  pool: 5
  timeout: 5000
```

Here is link that I am following

https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/sqlite3#getting-a-sqlite-error-even-though-it-is-not-in-the-gemfile

Error in my terminal

```
remote:  !
remote:  !     Failed to install gems via Bundler.
remote:  !     Detected sqlite3 gem which is not supported on Heroku:
remote:  !     https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/sqlite3
remote:  !
remote:  !     Push rejected, failed to compile Ruby app.
remote: 
remote:  !     Push failed
remote: Verifying deploy...
remote: 
remote: !   Push rejected to orouge.
remote: 
To https://git.heroku.com/orouge.git
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://git.heroku.com/orouge.git'
```

Comment: make sure, gem file also

Comment: my question is how to set up database.yml specifically what to put in front of database??  ```database: sample_postgres_development```

Answer (score 0):

Well the code that you have is still referencing `sqlite`

```
  database: db/production.sqlite3
```

Use the other block that you have. Also, it might be possible that `sqlite` is referenced in your `Gemfile.lock`, but I would imagine that is overwritten when you deploy.

Here is a link to samples of database.yml files, make yours look like the one for postgres.

https://gist.github.com/jwo/4512764

Comment: my question is how to set up database.yml specifically what to put in front of database?? ```database: sample_postgres_development ```

Comment: I dont know how to set up my                                                                                                   ```database.yml``  so I added following    ``` development:
adapter: postgresql
encoding: unicode
database: username
pool: 5
username: username
password: none



test:
adapter: postgresql
encoding: unicode
database: username
pool: 5
username: username
password:



production:
adapter: postgresql
encoding: unicode
database: username
pool: 5
username: username
password: none ```   and I am getting these 2 errors in terminals now

Comment: ###### WARNING:
remote: 
remote:        No Procfile detected, using the default web server.
remote:        We recommend explicitly declaring how to boot your server process via a Procfile.
remote:        https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/ruby-default-web-server                     then i do this as suggested in the link ``` web: bundle exec rails server -p $PORT ``` but says 'web' is not recognized  -bash: web:: command not found

Comment: Are  you going through a tutorial for deploying rails on heroku ? That is your best bet because you could run in to a number of issues. When you deploy to heroku you need a procfile. create a file called `Procfile` and put this in it. `web: bundle exec rails server thin -p $PORT -e $RACK_ENV` Source: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10237200/heroku-rails-procfile

Answer (score 0):

This happens when you've added postgres to your gemfile, but you've either:

1. Not removed sqlite3 from your gemfile
2. You've not run `bundle install` after adding postgres and removing sqlite3

Comment: my question is how to set up database.yml specifically what to put in front of database?? ```database: sample_postgres_development ```